# how to apply "jQuery Raty" to all rows of a TemplateField ( Item Template ) of Gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, templatefield, raty

I had tried to use "jQuery Raty" to populate stars to all rows of a specific TemplateField ( Item Template ) of Gridview in ASP.NET with following codes, but only the first row of the specific TemplateField ( Item Template ) were populated with 5 stars. Other rows were empty.
I will be appreciated if you can tell me How to apply "jQuery Raty" to all rows of a template column of Gridview in ASP.NET. Thanks in advance!

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DisplayStarRating">
<ItemTemplate>
<div id="star"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#star').raty();
</script>
 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

BTW I use following C# codes to bind the GridView with DataSet and above HTML code to append a  template column to  Display Star Rating  with   "jQuery Raty"  for all rows of the template column.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
            GridView1.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using the element id use the element class to populate more items

Comment: thanks so much for your prompt reply. Sorry. I am new to use the element class. Would you please provide more information about it? thanks！

Comment: can populate into other rows with following,still need to refine. $('.star').raty();